# How to build recommendation system for e-commerce

Tags: e-commerce, recommendation-engine, apache-spark-ml

I would like to build recommendation system for e-commerce. I'd like to suggest customer products based on products, which he has watched. Products watched by this customer would be compare with products watched be other customers and in result I would give customer best matches. More over, I would like also boost products, which customers has bought, while they have been watching products similar to products watching by current customer.

I’ve tried to use Amazon Machine Learning, but it’s not the system designed for that kind of problem.

Also I’ve tried to build it on Spark Machine Learning, but most of examples, describe cases based on film rating. I do not really know how to rewrite it on my case.

So I’d like to ask you if you know any recommendation systems which I can use to do that or maybe you know how to use Spark ML engine to build this kind of recommedation system?